# Printing debug values in a cryptographic exchange

Tags: java

I have created this basic program to implement the Diffie-Hellman algorithm. I want `s` to be a randomly generated prime number, and `q` to be a randomly generated integer. `sk1` and `sk2` are shared keys which are also generated randomly. `pk1` and `pk2` are modulus calculated values which I have to prove are equal to each other. I think my formula is correct but I am not sure how to print the values of `s`, `q`, `sk1`, `sk2`, `pk1` and `pk2` to verify my requirements. My code is pasted below and I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with the print statements.

```java
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.Random;
import java.math.*;

public class DH {
    public static void main(String [] arg) {
         
        int s, q;
        double sk1, sk2, pk1 = 0, pk2 = 0;
        Random generator = new Random();
        s = generator.nextInt(50000);
        q = generator.nextInt(50000);
    
        sk1 = generator.nextInt();
        sk2 = generator.nextInt();
    
        if(s==1 || s==2) {
            for(int i = 2; i< (int)(s/2); i++) {
                if(s/i != (int)(s/i)) {
                    double a= Math.pow(q,sk1);
                    pk1 = a%s;
    
                    double b= Math.pow(q, sk2);
                    pk2 = b%s;
    
                    if(pk1==pk2) {
                        System.out.println("true");
                    }
    
                    System.out.println(s);
                    System.out.println(q);
                    System.out.println(sk1);
                    System.out.println(sk2);
                    System.out.println(pk1);
                    System.out.println(pk2);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code by selecting it and pressing CTRL+K.

Comment: Btw, what is your question? You're saying you're not sure how to print the values, but you're calling `System.out.println`. So what's happening? Are they not printed out?

Answer (score 1):

Your print statements are inside of your if case.  Have you considered that `s != 1 or s != 2` ?

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.Random;
import java.math.*;

public class DH {
    public static void main(String [] arg) {

        int s, q;
        double sk1, sk2, pk1 = 0, pk2 = 0;
        Random generator = new Random();
        s = generator.nextInt(50000);
        q = generator.nextInt(50000);

        sk1 = generator.nextInt();
        sk2 = generator.nextInt();

        if(s==1 || s==2) {
            for(int i = 2; i< (int)(s/2); i++) {
                if(s/i != (int)(s/i)) {
                    double a= Math.pow(q,sk1);
                    pk1 = a%s;
                    double b= Math.pow(q, sk2);
                    pk2 = b%s;

                    if(pk1==pk2) {
                        System.out.println("true");
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(q);
        System.out.println(sk1);
        System.out.println(sk2);
        System.out.println(pk1);
        System.out.println(pk2);        
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ebo Mike it is not printing value

Comment: @amir none of those condition work :( ... and S is supposed to be a prime no.

Comment: @Ebo Mike: it is building successfully but not printing value so I cant verify what I wish to do

Comment: See my answer. The s/i condition doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @user524547: `s` may be "supposed to be" a prime number, but your code won't make it so.  The line `s = generator.nextInt(50000);` will cause `s` to be some random integer between 0 and 50000.  Since your code that actually prints the outputs is wrapped in an `if` block that tests `if(s == 1 || s == 2)` you will only ever run it 1/25000 of the time.  And as EboMike points out, your `if(s/i != (int)(s/i))` will prevent it from running anything else on those other times either.

Comment: can you point me to a general syntax of prime no. if i am formulating it wrong .

Comment: I will try my program again with right formulation of prime no.

Answer (score 1):

You're only ever doing anything if  `if(s/i != (int)(s/i))`. Since both `s` and `i` are integers, it's unlikely that this condition will ever be true.

(To clarify: With "unlikely", I mean that this condition couldn't possibly be true. `s/i` returns an integer, and `(int)(s/i)` will return the exact same integer.)

Comment: Its the core of the Diffie Hellman algorithim that you need to find the larget factors of s that is a whole number. As he is looping through all values of i to half of s the program will surly find at least one factor when i = 1 and probably a higher value.

Comment: True, except that `i` and `s` are both integers, so `s/i` returns an integer, and `(int)(s/i)` returns the same integer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever use floating point arithmetics for cryptography. Especially for exponentiation you need results with more precision than a `double` can give you. Use `BigInteger` instead.

While you are testing, you should not use "new" random numbers each time. Use `new Random(0)` instead so that you can reproduce your computations the next time you start the debugger.

How do you guarantee that `s` is a prime number? I cannot see it from the code.

Please indent your code properly and consistently. <strike>Since you are using Eclipse, all you need to do is to press Ctrl-Shift-F once.</strike>

Comment: how to do you generate a random BigInteger ?

Comment: and I am using Netbeans v6.9.1

Answer (score 1):

As s an intger generated by:

```
s = generator.nextInt(50000);
```

There is a 25,000 to 1 chance that :

```
if(s==1 || s==2) {
```

will ever be true.
Perhaps yo umeant if s > 2?

Comment: I am trying to make S as a prime no. and 1 and 2 are prime no.s

Comment: Please read the post carefully and think about it! You are selectign a random number s between 1 and 50,000. You then execute the body of your code only if s has value 1 or 2!